# Html page must be redirect after closing jquery ui popup close after sometime in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, scala, spring-mvc

**Html page must be redirect after closing jquery ui popup close after sometime in spring mvc**

hi my project based spring mvc project in scala,
i have a specific need when i submit the form via submit button jquery-ui pop showed after a x time it must be close automatically then i need to redirect to next page
But the problem is when i submit the form it'l redirect to next page very fast i canonot actuall see the popup
**script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){


    $("#alert").dialog({

        modal: true,
        open: function() { var foo = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
               foo.dialog('close');
            }, 3000);
        }
    });

  });
});
```

**spring controller in scala**

```
  @RequestMapping(value = Array("/Next.html"), params = Array({ "submit" }))
  def next(model: ModelMap, @RequestParam opt: String, opt1: String, opt2: String): String = {

    processing(opt, opt1, opt2)
    println(opt + " " + opt1 + " " + opt2)
    b += 1

    "redirect:/student/test.html"
  }
```

**my html form**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/Next.html}">
            <div th:each=" q: ${question}">


                <input  type="submit" name="submit"
                     />
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is submit button will submit the form as soon you click on it.
Make the type of button as button instead of submit so that it will not submit your form on clicking.
Now bind your click function on this button like you did with a little modification suggested below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){


    $("#alert").dialog({

        modal: true,
        open: function() { var foo = $(this);
            setTimeout(function() {
               foo.dialog('close');
               $('form').submit();
            }, 3000);
        }
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: does it effect the controller??

Comment: No not at all. At the end form is getting submitted but only after the timeout completes and dialog is closed. So it won't effect the controller.

Comment: it does..the popup is closing so fast

Comment: I think this is because when you call dialog('close') it takes some time to accomplish the transition associated with closing the dialogue but calling form.submit immediate after the dialog('close') is not giving it sufficient time so you can see the documentation of dialog and call form.submit on close event of the dialog so the form gets submitted only after close transition gets completed.

Comment: i think the controller forcefully change the page thats why is not properly showing popup

Comment: Its not the controller. Its your browser which is making another request as soon as you say form.submit. Your controller can not do anything untill it gets any request mapped with any of its URL.